# How to get HDFS file system check info

Tags: scala, hdfs

I am currently trying to get information of files' storage size and number of block on HDFS in my application. Now the only way I find is that running the `fsck` command in application. After that parsing the output to get size and blocks. Is there other way to do that? Is there any API provided that I can call and directly get the number of blocks? Need advice. THX.

Comment: For storage size, you can use `FileSystem.getContentSummary(path)` which returns a `ContentSummary` object that has a `spaceConsumed` member. For block count, I'm not familiar with any alternative - you can run fsck via HTTP call (`http://<NameNodeHost>:50070/fsck?ugi=<User>&blocks=1&path=<Path>`) instead of an OS command, but it returns the same textual result that you'd have to parse...

Comment: @TzachZohar thx, I think the restAPI is also a acceptable way for me. I really appreciate your example. I didn't find much example about HDFS restAPI. Your comment is really helpful.

Comment: @TzachZohar also I come across an issue. After I try to do fsck val HTTP call. I get an error with `Problem accessing /fsck. Reason: NOT_FOUND`. Any idea?

Comment: Hmm.. might not be supported on your HDFS version maybe - I've tested it on version `2.6.0-cdh5.8.3`, perhaps you're using an older version?

Comment: @TzachZohar yes, I am currently using `cdh5.5.0`